# Отправка файла на сервер с помощью IdHTTP

Tags: idhttp, delphi

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые эксперты. Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: нужно отправить файл на некоторый сервер. Делал так:

```
http:=TIdHTTP.Create;
stream:=TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;
http.Request.ContentType:='multipart/form-data';
stream.AddFile('file', 'e:\sampl.xml', 'multipart/form-data');
Http.post(SERV_URL, stream);
stream.free;
http.free;
```

к сожалению, ничего путнего из этого не выходит. Ничего плохого не происходит, равно как и хорошего. Короче, на сервере ничего нового не появляется. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема.

Уважаемые эксперты. Извините за вопрос, проблема оказалась не во мне и не в моем коде, а в разгильдяйстве 3-х лиц. Просто файлы сохранялись не там где было договорено. Вопрос закрыт

2Vahan Av нормально все и стримом сохраняется. Другие компоненты кроме TIdHTTP использовать нельзя было по ТЗ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну естественно
Http.post(SERV_URL, stream);
Отправляет post запрос на сервер чтоб этот файл появился на сервере нужно еше этот запрос на сервере обработать (хотя честно говоря не знаю как можно stream на сервере обработать)
Лучше воспользуйтесь TidFTP.